# Decrypt a file in iOS Objective-C encrypted using RijndaelManaged class

Tags: c#, objective-c, encryption, aes, rijndael

I am encrypting files in C# using the RijndaelManaged class using the following code:

```
RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

byte[] keyArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("**Random Passphrase**"); // 256-AES key             
RMCrypto.Key = keyArray;
RMCrypto.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create);

ICryptoTransform cTransform = RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor();
CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, cTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);

byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 16384];
int len;
while ((len = fsIn.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    cs.Write(buffer, 0, len);
}

fsIn.Close();
cs.Close();
fsCrypt.Close();
```

How can I decrypt the same file in iOS Objective-C and use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the Apple supplied CommonCrypto functions. There are several answers here on SO with code and several 3rd party project such as RNCryptor that encapsulate CommonCrypto including availability via CocoaPods.

What is necessary is matching all the parameters such as key size (128/192/256), key, iv, data, mode and padding.

AES is a subset of Rijndael and generally there is no compatibility issue as long as the block size is 128 bits.

See my SO [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10078625/451475).

Comment: Hey Zaph, I was trying your example and all the other samples and the common thing is that they all need an IV to decrypt the data, but this code here, doesn't use an IV for encryption and we've used the same for android and it doesn't use an IV as well.
I'm bummed as to how to provide the necessary parameters for the decryption to go smooth.

Comment: ECB mode does not require an iv but it provides weaker security, if possible use CBC mode with an iv

Comment: That is not a problem, the client , but how do I use ECB mode in iOS? Can you please point me to a Sample? Thanks

Comment: To use ECB mode add the option: `kCCOptionECBMode` and an iv of nil. To see how bad ECB mode can be see the images of the Penguin in the [WikiPedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation).

Comment: @manishKungwani : i am stuck in same problem, i don't know how and where to use iv in my code, One more thing, if you can help me in getting about ECB.

Comment: @Piyushmatta If you are having difficulty open a new question. Add the code you have along with test data and a description of the problem you have.

Comment: @Piyushmatta the answer works as it is .. as Zaph said, attach your code if there is an issue ..

Comment: @zaph : how can i use CBC  mode in ios ? i want to use IV in my encryption and for that i need cbc mode, how can i use cbc ?

Comment: CBC mode is the default for Common Crypto CCCrypt.